# Responsive slider fixed background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate a slider like on the following link in the sidebar called recent results: http://demo.themeum.com/sportsline/. Here you see an slider with a fixed background and with content sliding. i've tried recreating it by different frameworks, but it does not seem to be responsive? so how could i recreate something similar as in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap. That is what they are doing in your link:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/